# How to get a list of friends the user invited in a Facebook app with Requests 2.0

Tags: facebook, request

im using new Requests 2.0  (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

So i set up everything and is working ok - i have only one problem left. When a user selects 50 friends to invite to my app. What i need is the user ID's of these people invited (so user cannot invite them again).

What i do now is to get every user id with a call like this:
$data = $facebook->api('/'.$request_id.'/');
$user_id = $data['to']['id'];

So i loop trough all 50 $request_id's and get the user's id's.

BUT this is afcourse very slow, since i do 50 request (sometimes it doesnt work at all...). So is there any better way to get invited users id from new Requests 2.0 dialog???

Comment: No, actually that's the way. You can use the [batch api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/batch/) to minimize the requests.

Comment: Hmm, i checked batch api - but there is a limit to 20 requests, so this is also not a solution. I also checked fql (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/), but there is no table for requests (or i missed something?). anyway, i just can't belive im the only one with same problem???

Answer (score 0):

At this stage it doesnt look like there is an alternative strategy to looping through all the request_ids.
Why not try splitting the request_ids you get back from the dialog into smaller groups and maybe placing a short pause between processing groups... or utilize the batch requests again pause slightly between requests. These requests will take time - you'll have to disable the trigger for the dialog until you finish processing the request_ids and then add those user IDS to the `exclude_ids` property.

If you are limiting your users to send only one request to each user you might consider also managing your requests only when they are responded to...
You allow users to send as many requests to as many users as they want - then when that request is responded to you loop through THAT users outstanding requests and delete ones from the same user, similar to what you mentioned above :

`$data = $facebook->api('/'.$request_id.'/','DELETE');`

Answer (score 0):

What I did was get the list of user's friends and then just look up friend names using the user IDs that I got from the request info.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the full details of all requests in a single call:

`https://graph.facebook.com/?access_token=<ACCESS TOKEN>&ids=<CSV LIST OF THE REQUEST IDS>`